# Displaying SNMP trap on a web page (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, log4j, snmp

i've a project that i build using struts and spring. I'm confuse how to show received trap on view tier(jsp) of project. Could anyone tell me some trick?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a trap receiver, first off, that can decode the SNMP protocol.  There are many available, but an example of a free one would be the [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) snmptrapd program that can receive traps, format the results and optionally call an external program.  It should certainly be able to do what you want, but there are many commercial products that can as well.

Comment: i use TrapReceiver class from this blog http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/generating-trap-in-snmp-using-snmp4j/

i'm confused to return the value that was captured in processPdu method. Or, is any other trick to display the processPdu method result on a web page?

Comment: Then your question is very vague, as you don't say at all in your question what you asked about in the comment.  You need to give a more accurate question stating what software you're using and what questions you have about it.

Comment: maybe I'm too newbie to this. What i have done what just read the blog, copy the code, and compile the code. And what i have see that the result displayed on the console. And i want to ask, how to displaying it on a web page. Sorry, I confuse what are you asked to me. I use snmp4j-2.0.2 library and log4j-1.2.16. Thank you, and im sorry for confusing,